# blender guru donut tutorial ... sprinkle inside my bun

Tags: shaders

[image][image][image][image]Greeting to all,
I have completed my donut with blender guru tutorial and it was looking great and I saved it but when I opened my saved donut file today its looking like this . I do not know why but the sprinkles seems to be somehow added inside the donut bun and it is not applying shading nodes properly nor the texture paint. please help
I believe the problem is somewhere here I guess? In the highlighted part
this is what it shows in texture paint
As you can see clearly in this shading view image that how the sprinkles are indulged in the donut bun.

Comment: hello, it's a bit hard to understand what you mean, maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I just uploaded my file would you mind checking it ? That would be a great help @moonboots

Comment: @tanyagarg: your upload went wrong somehow....

Comment: @tanya garg you need to copy paste us the link it gives you

Comment: https://pasteall.org/media/5/f/5f5e37b127d1055f751f68c483a373cd.blend here s the link but I do'nt know why it's showing donut bun in pink colour by using the link @moonboots

Comment: pink is because the image is missing, you can pack the image (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend). That said I'm not sure what's your problem here, I can't see any particle inside the mesh

Comment: @moonboots would you mind checking the images i just added in my question?

Comment: please pack your images and share again

Comment: https://pasteall.org/media/f/5/f5241d6a050ac4f2035c5e2be95808b1.blend here is the packed images @moonboots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an image called *donut texture* in an *Image Texture* node of your material. Open the *Image Editor* and look what is this image, it's nothing else than a render of your donut, so you're just projecting an image of your donut on your donut. You need to use another image (or paint over this image):

[image]

Comment: okay, now i get it thank you so much @moonboots for your time and efforts

Comment: i am trying to paint over my image but could not , can you help me in this please @moonboots ?

Comment: once you've switched to Texture Paint mode, make sure that you have a bit of Strength (top header menu or in the N panel > Brush Settings > Strength)

Comment: i am trying to do that but my donut bun is showing purple color in texture paint which means they are not connected and i do'nt know how to , can you guide me please @moonboots ?

Comment: It's a bit hard to explain through Blender Stack Exchange, maybe follow some tutorials, example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9nE2Xg6Jgk

Comment: okay, i will and once again thank you so much @moonboots